# index.php url need to hide from homepage of php website

Tags: php, url

The website www.indowesterncaterers.com/ has menu in header.php

```
    <ul>

        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'about-us.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="about-us.php">About US</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'plan-your-wedding.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="plan-your-wedding.php">PLAN YOUR WEDDING</a>

<ul>
<li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'venues.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="venues.php">venues</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'invitations.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="invitations.php">Invitations</a></li>
     <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'flower-decoration.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="flower-decoration.php">flower decoration</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'mehandi-function.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="mehandi-function.php">mehandi function</a></li>

    </ul>


</li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'wedding-catering.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="wedding-catering.php">wedding catering</a></li>
        <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'image-gallery.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="image-gallery.php">Image Gallery</a></li>
<li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'special-offer.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="special-offer.php">special offer</a></li>
    </ul>
```

from other pages , like http://www.indowesterncaterers.com/wedding-catering.php

If I click on homepage , the url shows http://www.indowesterncaterers.com/index.php

I want to hide index.php url when clicked from other navigation urls.

The site in core PHP ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

try

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Comment: The solution is simple and clear 
I want to close the question , as it is solved .

Comment: Thats not how SO works. The questions and answers stay as a resource for other users that may have the same issues. You have done everything right so far.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DirectoryIndex is set to index.php, you should be able to use -

```
<li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php'){echo 'active'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```